# How do I find the position of substring in PowerShell after position x?

Tags: powershell

Is there a simple way to do so; I can't find any. Am I obliged to scan character by character?

I don't want a string as return, but a *position* so do not suggest SubString.

Comment: Depending on what you're looking to find in the string, it could be easier to use a Regular Expression. Can you post the string you need to scan and the substring you're looking for so we can provide a better answer?

Comment: I have modified my question : I want a position index not the substring.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To compliment [the answer from Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663644/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-substring-in-powershell-after-position-x/31663895#31663895):

The [String.IndexOf method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) is in fact a [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) method of the string object. This appears from the fact that it is case-sensitive by default (which is not common for PowerShell):

```
PS C:\> "WordsWordsWords".IndexOf("words")
-1
```

You might overcome this by setting the [`StringComparison`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) to `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`:

```
PS C:\> "WordsWordsWords".IndexOf("words", [System.StringComparison]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
0
```

But you might also consider the [`Select-String` *cmdlet*](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) which gives you more possibilities including [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
PS C:\> ("Words words words" | Select-String "words").Matches.Index
0
PS C:\> ("Words words words" | Select-String "words" -AllMatches).Matches.Index
0
6
12
PS C:\> ("Words words words" | Select-String "\w+" -AllMatches).Matches.Index
0
6
12
```

Answer (score 31):

Yes, you can. The [`IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) method has [an overload that takes a `startIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) argument:

```
PS C:\> "WordsWordsWords".IndexOf("Words")
0
PS C:\> "WordsWordsWords".IndexOf("Words", 2)
5
```

In the second example, we look for the index of the substring "Words" starting *after* character index 2.