# How to replace Substring between position x and position z by empty string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Replace method takes string as parameter not positions so I can't see how to do this with it. Is there any other method(s) which could be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove part of a string, from a given index, and with a specified length.

I assume this to be a follow-up to [your question about finding said index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663644/how-to-find-position-of-substring-in-powershell-after-position-x) - use that value as an argument to `Remove()`, and the length of the substring to specify *how much to remove*:

```
function Remove-Substring {
    param(
        [string]$String,
        [string]$Word,
        [int]$StartIndex
    )

    return $String.Remove($String.IndexOf($Word,$StartIndex),$Word.Length)
}
```

Example usage:

```
PS C:\> Remove-Substring -String "LumpsChumpsFlumps" -Word "umps" -StartIndex 2
LumpsChFlumps
```

Comment: To op used replace in the title. I would have guessed that he wanted to replace umps with amps or something.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, but I figured "replace [...] by empty string" -eq "remove"

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'd concatenate the substring from the beginning of the string up to position x with the substring from position z to the end of the string to remove text between positions x and z:

```
$s.Substring(0,$x) + $s.Substring($z)
```

Comment: Do you think the op meant to actually replace text instead of removing it?

Comment: "replace with empty string" === "remove".